# HIve Alter commnad to change rowformat

Tags: hadoop, hive, ddl, alter, bigdata

created a table in hive without rowformat delimited option.
Now need to add

```
rowformat delimited fileds terminated by ';' records terminated by '\n'
```

how to do it, please help, Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Hive assigns the default `LazySimpleSerDe` as the Serde Library to the table which is not created with one. Alter the hive table by applying the serde properties to it,

```
ALTER table TBLNAME set SERDEPROPERTIES('field.delim' = ',');
```

By default, the rows are newline delimited.